# mysql - complex query combining pivot table, count, group, union, frequency, join and order

Tags: mysql, count, pivot-table, union, frequency-distribution

I have the following table where a1 is the age which can be repeated. g1 is the genders where 0 denotes male and 1 denotes female.

```
| a1 | g1|    
.................    
|   40 |   0 |    
|   48 |   1 |      
|   47 |   0 | 
|   52 |   0 |       
|   64 |   1 |      
|   50 |   1 |     
|   63 |   1 |     
|   57 |   0 |
```

I want to show the number of males and females according to the ages with the sum of males and females per row. I couldn't get the desired result.

```
| a1 |male|female|total|    
-----------------------------
| 40 | 120 | 80 | 200 |     
| 48 | 130 | 90 | 220 |     
| 47 | 140 | 70 | 210 |      
| 52 | 150 | 40 | 190 |     
| 64 | 160 | 45 | 205 |     
| 50 | 170 | 30 | 200 |     
| 63 | 180 | 30 | 210 |     
| 57 | 190 | 50 | 240 |
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. The above is maybe clear enough, but, for next time, please consider providing a properly representative data set, and corresponding result set. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CASE WHEN:

```
select a1 as age, sum(case when g1=0 then 1 end) as male, sum(case when g1=1 then 1 end) as female, sum(case when g1 in (1,0) then 1 end) as total
group by a1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a select case  and sum()  based  on group by age for a selective aggregation

```
    SELECT  a1 age 
        , SUM(CASE WHEN g1=0 THEN 1 END)  male
        , sum(CASE WHEN g1=1 THEN 1 END)  female
        , SUM(CASE WHEN g1=0 THEN 1 END)  +sum(CASE when g1=1 THEN 1 END)  total
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY a1
```

Comment: Note that as it's mysql, you don't really need the case bit - and the total is possibly a bit long-winded